# Update DB with Python. Can Mysql ignore ' style marks in content?

Tags: python, mysql

I want to add an entry to a table using python. But when the input contains special characters (especially ' ) the append fails, showing the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'm a small paragraph. But I have special 'marks' like ,' ' WHERE pid=1' at line 1")
```

My Python Codes:

```
import MySQLdb

db=MySQLdb.connect(host='host',user='usr',password='psw',db='db',charset='utf8mb4',)
mycursor = db.cursor()
message = "I'm a small paragraph. But I have special 'marks' like "",' "
sql = "UPDATE mybb_posts SET message='" + message + "' WHERE pid=1;"
mycursor.execute(sql)
db.commit() 
print(sonuc)
```

I'm try to Edit the **message** and removing the ' , " signs everything works fine.

I know this is an expected error. Because Mysql can see all ' signs as a thread. But adding the ' sign is mandatory. Can Mysql ignore ' style marks in message content? Or a different solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid appending values to the SQL query, you should escape the values as below

```
db=MySQLdb.connect(host='host',user='usr',password='psw',db='db',charset='utf8mb4',)
mycursor = db.cursor()
message = "I'm a small paragraph. But I have special 'marks' like"
sql = "UPDATE mybb_posts SET message= %s WHERE pid = %s"
val = (message, 1)

mycursor.execute(sql, val)
db.commit()
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_update.asp